# html5 video player on a website that will play a youtube link

Tags: html

i an working with online site and i want to have a video player that will allow only youtube links to play, and it will play on my video player...i need some idea...

thank you!..

Comment: Please consider rephrasing your question. It's not clear what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

Google has an IFrame which will automagically select FLASH or HTML5

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

BUT YOU CANNOT USE YOUR OWN VIDEO PLAYER!

Answer (score 1):

YouTube has an embeddable video player which supports HTML5.  It puts the video in an iframe and the code looks like this.

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

More information is available at the [YouTube API blog](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html).

This will not allow you to use your own player, but will let you show a YouTube video and their controls will be in HTML5 if supported by the user's browser.

Information about which browsers support their HTML5 player are available on the [YouTube HTML5 page](http://www.youtube.com/html5).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community. AFAIK youtube doesn't allow direct access to their video streams, which means you're stuck using their video player.

If they did, users would very easily be able to save any video posted on youtube, rather than needing to download an add-on to access the video.

Comment: I'm using the Youtube HTML5 trial and was viewing an embedded video. I was surprised to find that right-clicking the video title in the embedded player gave me two options: "Save Video As..." and "About HTML5". Surely Youtube wouldn't make it that easy, I thought? So I clicked the Save As option. And... it sent me to a Rickroll video. Google's sense of humor strikes again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the mediaelementJS Player](http://johndyer.name/html5-video-wrapper-for-youtube-and-vimeo-api-mediaelement-js/) but its not supported by every device.

Works eg. with: : iPhone 4, HTC One Android 4.1.2, iPod Touch 6.0.1, Nokia Lumina 920 WinPhone 8, Sony Ericson Xperia Android. But not with Sony Xperia P.